# Lightweight cross-platform cryptography-quality RNG

Tags: cryptography, random-number-generator

I am looking for a lightweight (< 500 SLOC) random generator that's suitable for cryptography. This needs to be C code that I can include in the SlipRock library (which I am developing).  Currently I use libsodium but it seems a shame to pull in such a (relatively) massive dependency, and conversations with potential users indicate that they would not want such a large dependency.  I am looking for something that I can include in my project.

At the same time, I don't want to write something myself.  This is crypto code, and so the usual “don't roll your own crypto” maxim applies.  Right now I am just planning to take some code from libsodium, but I would rather use a standalone library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libsodium's default implementation fits in a single, (currently) 371 lines of C code.

See the `randombytes/sysrandom/randombytes_sysrandom.c` file.